# Pivot in R and keep other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I have the following df in R:

| ID_A | Value_A | Boolean | Value_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 1 | -2 |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0 | -2 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | -0.3 | 0 | 1 |

And I want the following output:

| ID_A | Value_A_Boo_1 | Value_A_Boo_0 | Value_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.1 | -2 |
| 2 | 0.5 | -0.3 | 1 |

I think that is has something to do with pivot, but I am always loosing some of the informations of other columns. Basically I just want to modify Value A based on Boolean-column and keep ID_A and Value_B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a pivot to wide. You can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`. Check the `names_glue` argument, very useful to construct the new column names.

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Boolean", values_from = "Value_A", 
              names_glue = "{.value}_Boo_{Boolean}")

# A tibble: 2 × 4
   ID_A Value_B Value_A_Boo_1 Value_A_Boo_0
  <int>   <int>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1      -2           0.2           0.1
2     2       1           0.5          -0.3
```